# Bootstrap nav height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement navigation with nav-pills class on my website but when I use the code below, buttons in navigation are too big. I would like to change its height. Any solution?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Rekonstrukce</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Zemní práce</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Rodinné domy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lightbox"> 
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/rekonstrukce/pic1.jpg" alt=""> 
                </a>                  
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/750x450" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/750x450" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your css:

```
.nav>li>a {
    padding: 4px 6px !important;
}
```

(Adjust the padding values according to the size you need)